# Get similar sounding records

Tags: mysql, soundex

I want to find all duplicate names from contacts table whose name matches by sound.
Eg : Rita or Reeta , Microsoft or Microsift , Mukherjee or Mukherji.

I have used below query :

select contacts.id from contacts   INNER JOIN (SELECT first_name,last_name,count(*) as rows FROM `contacts` where deleted = 0 GROUP BY soundex(first_name),soundex(last_name) HAVING count(rows) > 1) as p where contacts.deleted=0 AND p.`first_name` sounds like contacts.`first_name` and p.`last_name` sounds like contacts.`last_name` ORDER BY contacts.date_entered DESC

The above query gives right results but takes a lot of time when there are many records.

Comment: try Explain your query and post the result in the question.

Comment: try caching the `soundex`ed first and lastname in additional columns and put indices on these

Comment: I doubt the query actually works, the order is `WHERE` and then `GROUP BY`..

Comment: This query is invalid. You left out the beginning when copying and pasting.

Comment: I am sorry , I had posted a wrong query earlier.Now have corrected it.